# Node Spawn process outliving the main node process

Tags: node.js, child-process

I want to start a process that will live on its own and continue to live even if the node application that started it dies.

To do so I am trying to use `child_process` and I did not manage to have the process live even if the node process die.

Here is my code:

```
const cp = require('child_process');

const process = cp.spawn('long_running_process', ['arg1'], {
    stdio: 'ignore',
    detached: true
});

process.unref();
```

This code follows the `child_process` documentation available here :

https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_options_detached

Comment: In that case it's hard to say what's going on without seeing what your process is doing. It seems like what you have should work (just based on the docs). Is it exiting the moment your main Node process dies? Maybe you could have that other process do some file logging to see if it's dying unnaturally. Maybe put a `close` or `exit` handler on the process in node...

Comment: @pushkin The process is dying as soon as the main Node process die correct. I already have a handler for the exit/kill event handlers in node but it does not help as I want the main node process to be able to die, but keep the spawn processes ongoing.